# Error simulating click on menu item with Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I'm exploring Robolectric features for testing Android app, I've a simple unit test to verify that activity `NoteEditor class` open when is performed a click menu item. The code is:

```
    @Before
    public void setup(){
    //
    mProvider = new NotePadProvider();
    mContentResolver = Robolectric.application.getContentResolver();
    mProvider.onCreate();
    ShadowContentResolver.registerProvider(NotePad.AUTHORITY, mProvider);
    activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(NotesList.class).create().start().resume().visible().get();
}

    @Test
    public void menuAddShouldStartTheEditorActivity() throws Exception {
    // create reference to menu item "menu_add"
    MenuItem item = new TestMenuItem(R.id.menu_add);
    // simulate click item
    activity.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    ShadowActivity shadowActivity = shadowOf(activity);
    // get next started activity
    Intent startedIntent = shadowActivity.getNextStartedActivity();
    ShadowIntent shadowIntent = Robolectric.shadowOf(startedIntent);

    assertThat(shadowIntent.getComponent().getClassName(), equalTo(NoteEditor.class.getName()));
}`
```

it work's fine only the first piece of code, but when I execute the code line: 
`ShadowIntent shadowIntent = Robolectric.shadowOf(startedIntent);` 
Robolectric give me

```
[Error]: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.roboelectric.notepadtest.SimpleTest.menuAddShouldStartTheEditorActivity(SimpleTest.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) (...)
```

any idea why? Thanks in advance

Comment: `getNextStartedActivity()` will return null here. What do you want to test precisely?

Comment: Why is null? I want to verify that NoteEditor activity is opened after `activity.onOptionsItemSelected(item);` is performed...I've copied from [sample code](https://github.com/robolectric/RobolectricSample/blob/master/src/test/java/com/pivotallabs/HomeActivityTest.java), I only change the piece for click on MenuItem instead of Button (.performClick())...thanks for your reply

Comment: Can you check that `startedIntent` is `null` or not?

Comment: I'm not sure, if I log with `System.out.println("Log: " +startedIntent.getClass().getName());` I see on console `Log: android.content.Intent` ... If I log with `System.out.println("Log: " +startedIntent.getComponent().getClassName());` .. NullPointer error is raised..seems the startedIntent(object) is not empty, but is empty derived component?

Comment: It seems `getComponent()` returns `null` here. `shadowIntent` is also `null`? Are you sure that line causes the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Same result for shadowIntent, class name is `org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowIntent` but component name raise the `NullPointerException`...I'm sure about NullPointer? Junit failure trace report this exception, so I've no other information...thank again for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it bypassing component and using intent to verify correct activity lifecycle, so my test case became

```
@Test
public void menuAddShouldStartTheEditorActivity() throws Exception {
// create reference to menu item "menu_add"
MenuItem item = new TestMenuItem(R.id.menu_add);
// simulate click item
activity.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
ShadowActivity shadowActivity = shadowOf(activity);
// get next started intent from shadow
Intent startedIntent = shadowActivity.getNextStartedActivity();
// define expected intent (Editor class)
Intent expectedIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, NoteColumns.CONTENT_URI);
// verify it 
assertThat(startedIntent, equalTo(expectedIntent));
}
```

I don't know why, but getComponent() is always null because onCreate() in the AUT next activity (Editor), is never executed by Robolectric.

Comment: Robolectric [official guide](http://robolectric.org/starting-components/) assert `(..)Because Robolectric is a unit testing framework, the <2-nd>Activity will not actually be started, but we can check that the <1-st>Activity fired the correct intent(..)` so I think this is tha reason why getComponent() return alway null.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to take a shadow of the Intent. Simply do:

```
Intent startedIntent = shadowActivity.getNextStartedActivity();
assertThat(startedIntent.getComponent().getClassName(), equalTo(NoteEditor.class.getName()));
```

Comment: From the comment it turned out `getComponent()` returns `null` for @giovanni.

Comment: Hi Daniel thanks for your reply, I simplify the code as you suggest, but I take always the NullPointer exception. I've injected log print in AUT (Application Under Test) to see the flow of calls by test case. I've noted that this piece of code in **NotesList.java** `startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, getIntent().getData()));` is executed, but the LOG in **NoteEditor.java** class (injected in `onCreate()` event) never is printed.!